# How do I specify the output file name when using pander's live report generation?

Tags: r, pander

I can create a report object, but when I export() it, there is a generic file name containing a random number. I want to be able to specify the file name.

```
for (report in c("file1", "file2", "file3")) {
 myReport <- Pandoc$new(author="Jerubaal",title="What's my file name?", format="docx")
 myReport$add.paragraph(paste("This is", report))
 myReport$export(open = FALSE)
}
```

This gives me files with names such as

- pander-1c246b334f70.docx
- pander-1c246b334f70.md

I have tried adding these to Pandoc$new() and also to myReport$export(), but to no avail:

- output=report
- file=report
- filename=report

I will be looping through a lot of things, each of which needs its own report file, so I can't manually rename the files efficiently.

How do I specify the output file name?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first or `f` argument based on the [sources](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/R5.R#L109). E.g.:

```
myReport <- Pandoc$new(author="Jerubaal",title="What's my file name?", format="docx")
myReport$add.paragraph("This is it.")
myReport$export('this_is_the_file_name.docx', open = FALSE)
```

Please feel free to send a pull request or [suggestion](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues?state=closed) for an updated documentation.

Comment: Thank you - that worked, although I didn't need to include the file extension.